# Выбрать записи из таблицы, у которых в одной из колонок есть соответствие с колонкой другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть таблица ITEMS с колонками ITEM, NAME

```
 ITEM            NAME
-------------    -----
First record     Name1
Second record    Name2
Tratata          Name3
Ololo            Name4
Something third  Name5
```

Есть таблица VALUES с колонкой VALUE

```
VALUE
---------
rrrrrrrr
rewsjh
First
Third
```

Можно ли написать запрос, который будет вытягивать из ITEMS записи по соответствию - записи из VALUE входят в ITEM из ITEMS.
Т.е. на выходе должно получиться:

```
 ITEM            NAME
-------------    -----
First record     Name1
Something third  Name5
```

Comment: `SELECT ITEMS.ITEM, ITEM.NAME FROM ITEMS JOIN VALUES ON VALUES.VALUE = ITEM.NAME`, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл такое решение:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS AS I
JOIN VALUES AS V on I.ITEM like '%' + V.VALUE + '%'
```